# ADB tcpip command without cable

Tags: android, adb, remote-access, remote-server, tcp

I need remote ADB shell..
I know that we have to issue "ADB tcpip ".. to change ADB server to TCP listening mode.

But, the problem is that my phone is not rooted, and I do not have USB cable.
I can't issue tcpip command since I do not have USB cable,,
I can't change default.prop file as the phone is not rooted.

Is there any other ways to change ADB server to TCP listening mode???

Answer (score 2):

I found an articel that says you can execute `setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555` to make tcpip mode autostart after reboot.

The problem is, you must run this command as root.

On my device unfortunally the command `su` doeas not exist.

Here is the orginal [Permanent network debugging on android](http://omelina.com/permanent-network-debugging-on-android/?unapproved=834&moderation-hash=e366ec2f08a036ed33f083b18df3d506#comment-834article)

**EDIT:** I discovered, that the `su` command is only available when your device is rooted.
So the solution only works when you have a rooted phone

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: no, you can't.

As you said, you can't access the prop file and don't have a cable to change with ADB. The only way is you find the port via an Android terminal emulator (a.k.a Termux)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a better answer:
YES, YOU CAN!!

When you try to execute "adb tcpip 5555" without an USB cable, it returns:
"error: no devices/emulators found"

Emulators?? After googling I found the way and made a batch file that connects my device directly through WIFI, no cables needed at all:

```
set /p ip= Device IP: 

:CONNECT
if "%CD%"=="C:\" goto ROOT
cd ..
goto CONNECT

:ROOT
cd ...Android\Sdk\emulator
echo.
echo Starting emulator...
start /MIN emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_29_x86 -no-window
(you can check other avaliable devices with "emulator -list-avds")

cd ..
cd platform-tools
adb wait-for-device
echo.
echo Emulator started.
echo Connecting with device...
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect %ip%
echo.
echo Closing emulator...
(you need it just to be able to execute "adb tcpip 5555")
adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill
(you can check the name with "adb devices")
```

Comment: It does not work!
cannot connect to 192.168.100.121:5555: No connection could be made because the target computer
as actively refused. (10061)

Answer (score -2):

To enable wireless debug need to configure the ADB command. (in mac os)

**Step1:-** First of all need to enable adb command. (check SDK tool and install command-line tools)

**Step2:-** connect the device with a USB cable after that run the below command.

command: `adb devices`

the above command will show a list of connected mobiles.

**Step3:-** after that, we need to configure TCPIP protocol:

e.g : `adb tcpip 5556`

**Step4:-** Run command to connect the device.

command: `adb connect your_ip:port_address`
eg:- `adb connect 192.168.1.152:5556`

Comment: "No cable", step 2 is impossible

Comment: yes, These steps are for connecting the first time.

Comment: Hello please, this is based on an old android studio I uploaded the answer on 2021. For latest android studio  please also check https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#:~:text=Pair%20Devices%20Using%20Wi%2DFi

Answer (score -3):

If you are using the stock android os system, then you can enable remote debugging in Settting -> developer options.

Comment: Hello!, what developer options are you talking about?

Comment: if I click USB debugging option enable, the ADB server is running as USB mode

Comment: @ccheng that only applies to some custom ROMs, like CyanogenMod. Not stock Android.

Comment: @Michael almost 6 years ago, yes. This is no longer relevant.